# How can I test a page behind a security firewall in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

In Symfony's cookbook, there is a page entitled [How to Simulate Authentication with a Token in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html). In it, it is said that:

> The technique described in [How to Simulate HTTP Authentication in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html) is cleaner and therefore the preferred way.

Also, on the page that the quotation above links to, the documentation says:

> The trick is to include the http_basic key in your firewall, along with the form_login key

This tells me that it is all right to have the `form_login` key, along with the `http_basic` key, and somehow `http_basic` should take precedence.

Here is my `config_test.yml` configuration file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        collect: false

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true

liip_functional_test:
    cache_sqlite_db: true

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                path:     %kernel.cache_dir%/test.db

security:
    firewalls:
        default:
            http_basic: ~
```

However, when I open my application in the `test` environment, I still get redirected to the login_form URL.

Why isn't setting the `http_basic` acting like the documentation says it should, namely it getting activated rather than `form_login`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5244#issuecomment-100795471), having the code I pasted in my original question works just fine. The reason it is loading the login form is because I am not logging in via http_basic. In other words, when I have both `form_login` and `http_basic` enabled, I can login both by providing the `PHP_AUTH_USER`/`PHP_AUTH_PASSWORD`, and by logging in through the form. In effect, I don't need different `security_*.yml` files; I just need to add `http_basic: ~` to the already-defined firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Just split `security.yml` to `security_test.yml` and `security_prod.yml`.
In `security_test.yml` put default security configuration (as delivered with Symfony) or other one, which doesn't have firewall restrictions.

Create a specific config file for test environment, like `config_test.yml` with

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: security_test.yml }
```

**note here** `config.yml` itself doesn't have any security imports, because You will receive some Exception about overriding `security` directive or smth.

Create a separate `config_prod.yml` with

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: security_prod.yml }
```

Now You have separate `security` for `test` and `prod` environments.

If Your environment naming is good, then Kernel will pick `config_test.yml` only when tests are executed. For development environment Your should use `config_dev.yml` instead of `config_test.yml`

Comment: I tried this. The problem is that I have to duplicate a lot of the settings in `config_test.yml` because it already includes `config_dev.yml`. If i want to do what you suggest, I must duplicate `config_dev.yml` inside `config_test.yml` so that I can include `security_test.yml`. I'm talking about the standard distribution; you can probably see what I'm talking about if you create a new application and try to have two security configurations. That's why I asked if there is a way to force the `security` key to be overridden.

Comment: Security cannot be overriden. To avoid duplication, move shared configuration to config.yml and override needed parts in config_*.yml

Comment: In the standard distribution, the shared configuration is already in `config.yml`. The stuff that are shared between `config_dev.yml` and `config_test.yml`, though, are not. For example, both of these environments (`dev` and `test`) contain the profiler, the toolbar, the `router_dev.yml` and so on. I will have to duplicate these if I don't want to include `config_dev.yml` inside `config_test.yml`.

Comment: The goal is to move security.yml from default config.yml to specific environments. As I said - security key can only be included once, if you don't want to organise your configuration a bit better, then probably wait for another release where this hopefully be possible.

Comment: I just added the section of the documentation that says it's all right to have `http_basic` along with `form_login`. I just don't understand how I can tell one should take precedence over the other.

Comment: As I said - by different `security_*.yml`